# Como faço para comparar uma string que faz parte de um arquivo txt e outra digitada pelo usuário em C?

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em programação e estou aprendendo a fazer manipulações com Strings, entretanto ainda estou um pouco confusa em algumas coisas kkkkkk. Enfim, com relação ao exercício tem-se um arquivo txt contendo o seguinte conteúdo "maria joao joao maria maria". O usuário ao digitar um nome (maria ou joão) o programa retorna um inteiro com a quantidade de vezes que esse nome aparece no arquivo.

**Entrada:** Maria

**saída:** 3

Não consegui avançar muito no programa, mas ele tá assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
int main()
{
  FILE *file;
  char frase [27];
  char palavra [8];

  file = fopen ("arquivo.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Erro na abertura do arquivo");
        exit(0);
        }
    scanf ("%s", &palavra);
    
    while (fgets(frase, 27, file)!= NULL){
        retorno = strcmp (palavra, frase); 
    }
    
    printf ("O número de vezes e %d", retorno);
    fclose (file);


}
```

Então, eu estava pensando em percorrer a string digitada pelo usuário, caractere por caractere, e comparar se cada valor desse na função strcmp retorna zero e daí tentar algo.

Comment: use `fscanf()` para ler do disco assim recebe a string pronta para comparar com a digitada

Answer (score 1):

Compare com essa versão

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {   printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");
        return(-1);
    }
    char palavra[8] = "joao";
    char     frase[80];
    unsigned total     = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", frase) == 1)
        total += (strcmp(palavra, frase) == 0);
    printf("O número de vezes e %d", total);
    fclose(file);
}
```

E entenda que pode ser mais simples usar `fscanf()` para ler o arquivo. Assim já recebe uma palavra por vez e pode comparar diretamente.

Teste sempre o retorno de `scanf()`. É ingênuo não fazer isso: no seu caso por exemplo, se não leu a palavra vai procurar o que?

```
    unsigned total     = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", frase) == 1)
        total += (strcmp(palavra, frase) == 0);
```

Um loop assim faz a conta que você quer. Entenda que `fscanf()` vai retornar 1 se conseguir ler um dado, e `strcmp()` vai retornar 0 se as strings forem iguais. Compare com seu código original. O que você quer é contar quantas vezes `fscanf()` lê a palavra procurada.